# Посчитать значение функции путем суммирования по разложению в ряд

Tags: c++

Дана задача - посчитать значение функции с помощью библиотечной функции и путем суммирования по разложению в ряд. Считать необходимо в заданном диапазоне - от a до b, через равные промежутки, количество которых - m, т.е. с шагом h = (b - a) / m; m, e - вводятся с клавиатуры. Вот код. Не вижу, почему сумма всегда выходит нулевой.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double a = 0.2, b = 1, e = 0.00000001;
    int m = 5;

    double h = (b - a) / m;

    cout << "xi        log(x/2)        S" << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        double xi = a + i * h;
        double Fx = log(xi / 2), s = 0, dn = (xi - 1) / (xi + 1), xi1 = (xi - 1) / (xi + 1);
        double current;

        for (int n = 0;; n++) {
            current = dn / (n + n + 1);
            if (current >= e) {
                s += current;
            } else
                break;
            dn *= xi1 * xi1;
        }

        cout << xi << "        " << Fx << "        " << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во вложенном цикле исправьте:

```
if(fabs(current) >= e){
```